# Python (int) and (int,)

Tags: python, tuples

Why `type((1))` is **int** and not a **tuple**? Whereas `type((1,))` gives **tuple**.

Comment: The (1,) syntax is the way to indicate a tuple of one element. (1) is simply 1 which is an integer.

Comment: Putting parentheses around something doesn't make it a tuple.

Answer (score 1):

That's also an answer to the question why we should use commas while defining a tuple with one value. Because tuples are not like lists which is unique in a way that we define it (using squared brackets) we have to add the comma to the value. In the first one `type((1))` inner paranthesis have no effect, so it's just a basic integer nothing else. Like when you define expressions in paranthesis to give them priority. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Python compiler treated (1) as 1 because of that  it is showing as int. that is  inbuilt behavior of python compiler.

```
>>> a = (1)
>>> print(a)
1
>>> a = (1,)
>>> print(a)
(1,)
```